# RegExp - Replace all matches between two substrings

Tags: regex

Is it possible to replace all matches between two sub strings in one regular expression?

My case is that I want to inject HTML after the **li** tag but only inside myList.

Before:

```
<ul class="myList">
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

After (... would be the injected markup):

```
<ul class="myList">
    <li>...List item</li>
    <li>...List item</li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> My case is that I want to inject HTML after the li tag but only inside myList.

Other than for trivial cases where it's easy to write a "quick, hacky" script to get the job done, [you should never use regular expressions to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

A "quick, hacky" script in this case could be e.g. to search for:

```
<ul class="myList">.*<li>([^<]*)</li>(?=.*</ul>)
```

(Note: this probably needs to be a *multi-line* search; if there's no option for this then replace `.*` with `[\s\S]*`.)

...And then replace the value of the first match group (probably represented by `$1` or `\1`, depending on how you do this).

However, as per my link above, I'd like to emphasise that **this is not a perfect answer**. It is literally impossible to perfectly parse HTML with a regular expression.

To do this "properly", you must use an XML parser instead.

Comment: To give you an idea of just *some* of the flaws with my answer: `1.` What if there are more spaces in the HTML tags? `2.` What if there are other classes, IDs, style attributes, data attributes, etc in the HTML tags? `3.` What if there are multiple `<ul>` elements on the page? `4.` What if the `<li>` element contains a `<` character, e.g. a `<span>`? ........